# React Native tab in tab

Tags: react-native

I can't find if it's possible to create tabs in screen in React Native. IS there any way to do this? I mean, I already use StackNavigator and I can't understand how to add TabNavigator to screen from StackNavigator.

Update! Solution for this question is really simple, but for me, totally it wasn't obvious at all! Just set flex style to your view 
Example:

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}> // <- this is main screen
  <View> // <- this is screen header, you don't change this when click on Tab
    Some header
  </View>

  <View style={{ flex: 2 }}>
    <YourTabNavigator /> // <- your tabs (imported from external or same file)
  </View>
</View>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create tabs, as it is common design used in mobile applications. 
As I can't use comments to get some neccessary information. 
However I'll try to provide a generic answer.

If you are using react-navigation then you can create tabs with [TabNavigator provided by react-navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/tab#TabNavigator). Documentation contains the neccessary code as well.

You can also use some pure JS component like [react-native-tabs](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-tabs)

And if you are using some other navigation library, you can see the corresponding documentation.

Comment: Hey kamran! Thank you for your feedback. I just updated my question, because I think I didn't explain too good what I mean.